# How to migrate from Azure Static Web Apps to Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, openid, azure-static-web-app

Due to ./auth/me endpoint not containing a token when using an identity provider in Static Web Apps (more on this here: https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/794), I'm trying to migrate over to Azure App Service. I was able to set up and deploy everything in CI/CD and register the identity provider.

However, my app relies on custom programmatically assigned roles which is a feature of Static Web App. In particular, this feature relies on an Azure Function that fetches the assigned roles for a given user and based on which denies/allows etc. access to certain pages on the website, the roles are also made available in ./auth/me endpoint.

I do not understand how can I get similar functionality in Azure App Service.

Would appreciate any suggestion.

Thanks in advance!